# Search for a string in a stringbuilder and replace the whole line C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, stringbuilder

I'm using C# and I have a `stringbuilder sb` which has some lines containing strings separated by tabs as shown below:

```
1.14332    534335    4452435435
1.32332    534535    4354535435
1.34432    524335    4353235435
1.44332    534435    4352235435
.
.
.
```

what I want to do is to search in this string builder for a string, and if this string is found then I want to replace the whole line containing this string with another new string. So for example if the word I want to search for is `1.32332` then this line `1.32332    534535    4354535435`
 in `sb` will be replaced with a new substring for example `1.32332    664535    1154536665`. Any advice please?

Comment: StringBuilder is write-only. Call `ToString()` to get the string, do the replacement and you're done.

Comment: @CodeCaster but I don't know how I can replace the whole line containing the word I'm searching for?

Comment: And searching "C# replace line starting with" didn't yield any useful results?

Comment: Since you're in the realm of a `StringBuilder`, could you perhaps refactor your code to do this replace _before_ you've appended the values?

Comment: @JamesThorpe the point is that the stringbuilder already has values in it.

Comment: Indeed, but one of the reasons for using a `StringBuilder` in the first place is to not have to fiddle with entire strings.  If you can do this replace before the values are appended, it will _probably_ be more performant than converting to a string and doing a replace on that.

Comment: Any requirements for performance, if not - why regex? Also show what have you tried so far

Comment: if the stringbuilder is large then directly converting to string will impact performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex with the multiline option to replace lines, e.g. to replace lines containing "mystring" with "mynewstring":

```
var stringToMatch = Regex.Escape("mystring");
var lines = sb.ToString();
var regex = new Regex(string.Format(@"^.*\W{0}\W.*$", stringToMatch), RegexOptions.Multiline);
string result = regex.Replace(lines, "mynewstring");
```

Comment: what if  `mystring` was a string variable?

Comment: Plugging in stringToMatch without escaping is dangerous, unless you know what you are inserting does not get interpreted as special character in regex. The question has `.`, so you should pass the input string through Regex.Escape.

Comment: @OwenPauling: I'll downvote and comment, since not everyone wants other people fiddling with their posts.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me that you'd want to format a pattern like so:

```
String.Format(@"{0}\s*?\d+\s*?\d+", searchValue)
```

since the start of the line you're looking for can vary.  In your sample case the pattern, after formatting, would look like:

```
@"1\.32332\s*?\d+\s*?\d+"
```

which will find the line you're interested in for replacing.  Having said that, give this a try:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("1.14332    534335    4452435435");
sb.AppendLine("1.32332    534535    4354535435");
sb.AppendLine("1.34432    524335    4353235435");
sb.AppendLine("1.44332    534435    4352235435");

Console.WriteLine("Before: ");
Console.WriteLine(sb);

// Have to escape the decimal point to be part of the regex pattern
string searchValue = @"1\.32332";
string replaceValue = "1.32332    664535    1154536665";
Match match = Regex.Match(sb.ToString(), String.Format(@"{0}\s*?\d+\s*?\\d+", searchValue));
if (match.Success)
{
    sb.Replace(match.Value, replaceValue);
}

Console.WriteLine("After: ");
Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

Results:

```
Before:
1.14332    534335    4452435435
1.32332    534535    4354535435
1.34432    524335    4353235435
1.44332    534435    4352235435

After:
1.14332    534335    4452435435
1.32332    664535    1154536665
1.34432    524335    4353235435
1.44332    534435    4352235435
```

Comment: You forgot to escape `.` in the search value. In general, you should pass the input string through Regex.Escape before plugging it into the regex.

Comment: You might want to use the raw string literal syntax in C#, which is useful for situation like these where you have to double up ``\\`` due to the string literal syntax.

Comment: @nhahtdh You're referring using the @ against the strings?

Comment: Yes. [Verbatim string literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx) as called by Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use Regex You can also extract lines from stringbuilder and replace them with new string.

```
        StringBuilder yourStringBuilder; //Your stringbuilder
        StringBuilder newStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); // The result will store here
        string search = "1.32332";  // to search
        string replace = "1.32332    664535    1154536665"; // to replace

        var newsbstr = ReplaceWithLine(yourStringBuilder, search, replace).ToArray();


        // put array of strings into new stringbuilder.
        foreach (string s in newsbstr)
        {
            newStringBuilder.AppendLine(s);
        }
    }
```

This method will return strings line by line from stringbuilder. if the string found in line it will return `replace` otherwise it will return the extracted line(`sbline.ToString()`).

```
    private static IEnumerable<string> ReplaceWithLine(StringBuilder sb, string search,string replace)
    {
        StringBuilder sbline = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < sb.Length; i++)
        {
            char ch = sb[i];

            if (ch == '\n' || i == sb.Length - 1)
            {
                if (sbline.ToString().Contains(search))
                {
                    yield return replace;
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return sbline.ToString();
                }

                sbline.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                sbline.Append(ch);
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally You create array from IEnumerable and then you put them into new stringbuilder.